# Should i combine two table become one table to improve query performance

Tags: sql, database-design

I have two result table for calculate Monthly Allowace and OT-Allowance.
Should i combine two table become one table or use view or only join table in sql statement?

Example

[image]

[image]

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question becomes, why are there two tables in the first place? If both tables are always 1 to 1 (every time a row goes into first table it must also always go into second table) then yes, combine them, save the space of the duplicate data and indexes. If it is possible for the two tables to have different entries (one always a row per "incident" but the other may not or data sometimes in first table and sometimes in second) the keep them as two to minimize the dead space per row. The data should drive the table designs. You don't say how many rows you are talking. If the rows, tables, and DB are small, does it really matter other than trying to design well (always a good idea)?

Another related consideration is how much data is already in the current design and how much effort is needed to convert to a different design? Is it worth the effort? I prefer to normalize the data "mostly" (am not fanatical about it) but also tend to not mess with what isn't broken.

Sorry if you were wanting a more clear-cut answer...